# HTML form values to populate JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that I want the details submitted into a JS section to grab an API token.

Wondering if someone could help me a little.

I have a for and I want to place the values into some JS to get a Auth token. It works if I put the data in the code manually with the username and the password but not from the form. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<form id="apiauth">
   <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="emailresultsapp" name="email" value"">
   <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="pwdresultsapp" name="pwd" value"">
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="authenticate()">   
</form>

<input type="button" value="Generate a table" onclick="generateTable()" />


<script>
function authenticate (){
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("username", "document.getElementById('email')");
//formdata.append("password", document.getElementsByTagName("pwdresultsapp")[0]);
formdata.append("password", "document.getElementById('pwd')");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("URL", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => {console.log();
  getresults (result, parseJwt(result).username);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}

function parseJwt (token) {
    var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
    var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
    var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(window.atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));

    return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
};

function getresults (token, userid){
    generateTable();

}

function generateTable() {
  // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
  const tbl = document.createElement("table");
  const tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  // creating all cells
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    // creates a table row
    const row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
      // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
      // the end of the table row
      const cell = document.createElement("td");
      const cellText = document.createTextNode(`cell in row ${i}, column ${j}`);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }

    // add the row to the end of the table body
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }

  // put the <tbody> in the <table>
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  // appends <table> into <body>
  document.body.appendChild(tbl);
  // sets the border attribute of tbl to '2'
  tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}`enter code here

</script>
```

Comment: So show us what code you tried to actually _read_ the current values of those form fields then.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this and JS

Comment: `"document.getElementById('email')"` - that is a _text literal_, not a function call. And it is missing the part where you actually read the content of the `value` property.